# Having ng-class in angularjs replace instead of append to CSS classes?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, ng-class

I am doing an SPA to test out my AngularJS knowledge. In this app, I have a template where-by users can choose buttons to show how many days of weather forecast they want.

I am using Twitter Bootstrap classes with the AngularJS `ngClass` to dynamically have the Twitter Bootstrap `CSS` classes bound to the button elements depending on which button is selected.

What I wish to happen is, with using `ng-class` in the HTML of the template, if the button is chosen, it will then change the Bootstrap `CSS` class of that button to `btn btn-disabled` from `btn btn-primary`, so it cannot be selected, as it all ready is selected. I did this in the HTML for this template as so —

```
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <a href="#/forecast/1" class="btn btn-primary" ng-class="{  'btn btn-disabled' : days === '1' }">1 Day Forecast</a><a href="#/forecast/2" class="btn btn-primary" ng-class="{  'btn btn-disabled' : days === '2' }">2 Day Forecast</a><a href="#/forecast/3" class="btn btn-primary" ng-class="{  'btn btn-disabled' : days === '3' }">3 Day Forecast</a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <a href="#/forecast/5" class="btn btn-primary" ng-class="{  'btn btn-disabled' : days === '5' }">5 Day Forecast</a><a href="#/forecast/7" class="btn btn-primary" ng-class="{  'btn btn-disabled' : days === '7' }">7 Day Forecast</a><a href="#/forecast/10" class="btn btn-primary" ng-class="{  'btn btn-disabled' : days === '10' }">10 Day Forecast</a>
  </div>
```

However, when I run this, instead of replacing the Bootstrap `CSS` class for the element `btn btn-primary` and change it to `btn btn-disabled`, as desired; instead, it **appends** onto the element, so it becomes `btn btn-primary btn-disabled` all as one, and `btn-primary` overrules everything visually, so it winds up looking like this in the output —

```
<a href="#/forecast/1" class="btn btn-primary btn-disabled" ng-class="{  'btn btn-disabled' : days === '1' }">1 Day Forecast</a>
```

Naturally, this is **not** the desired effect I want here. Would someone please tell me how, in `AngularJS ngClass`, do i have it replace the Bootstrap `CSS` class, not just append it?

Comment: Please provide a plunkr or fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, using `ng-class` will add the classes when evaluated as true. So the solution is to add both options to `ng-class` so that either `btn-primary` or `btn-disabled` is added at any time.

```
<a href="#/forecast/1" class="btn" 
    ng-class="{'btn-disabled': days === '1', 'btn-primary': days !== '1'}">1 Day Forecast</a>
```

You also don't need to add the class `btn` to the `ng-class` since you want it to be used regardless of the value of `days`.

Comment: thank you for the answer. @Tristan. however, if i try the code your way, above, it still includes **both** CSS classes, `btn-diabled` and `btn-primary`, just now in reverse order. here is the HTML output from my dev tools in the browser —  `<a href="#/forecast/3" class="btn btn-disabled btn-primary" ng-class="{'btn-disabled': days === '3', 'btn-primary': days !== 3}">3 Day Forecast</a>`   ... see? it still does that, even coding it the way you suggest above. and because `btn-primary` is still in there, it takes precedence over everything. any other suggestions?

Comment: Try comparison to string. i.e. `days !== '3'`

Comment: Isn't days an int variable? @faddah, can you show us how `$scope.days` looks like? If you don't know the type of `$scope.days`, try `==` instead of `===`

Comment: Considering @faddah's existing code was evaluating true (it was adding `btn-disabled`), `days` must be a string. The data type will just depend on how it's set: `$scope.days = '1';` str, `$scope.days = 1;` int

Comment: that was it! @Tristan, you were so correct, i forgot to enclose the var in the second conditional in a `''` for a string. i did that with all of them, it's now all working now, perfectly! thank you, @Tristan, thank you @Marin Takanov! you folks & stackoverflow are my new best friends!!  